# bs4 - How to extract table data from website?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Here is the link,

https://www.vit.org/WebReports/vesselschedule.aspx

I'm using BeautifulSoup and my goal was to extract the table from it.
I wrote the code..

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url="https://www.vit.org/WebReports/vesselschedule.aspx"
html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
gdp_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"id": "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_VesselScheduleControl1_Grid1"})
```

The final line of code gave me an error displaying 'None'.

I'm new to this web scraping, can you help me find a solution to get the table?

Answer (score -1):

Why not pd.read_html(url)?

It will extract tables automatically

Answer (score -1):

Problem is that the **id** by which you are looking for this **table** is appended to the element dynamically via js and as **requests** library is only downloading files at URL, nothing is dynamically appended and in result Your table is without **id**

If you encounter a similar error in the future (element exists but bs4 cant find it) try saving the response as text to an HTML file and inspect it in your browser.

For your particular case this code could be used:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get("https://www.vit.org/WebReports/vesselschedule.aspx")

with open("tmp.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(resp.text)

bs = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)

table = bs.find_all("table")[6] # not the best way to select elements
rows = table.find_all("tr")
```

**Warning: Try avoiding such style of relative selecting, web pages are constantly updating and such code may procude errors in the future**

Answer (score -1):

I Parsed The Table and Added Each Rows in A List And Appended That To `Data` List
And Here You Go!..
And I Added The Total List In [[Hashbin]](https://hashb.in/#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)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.vit.org/WebReports/vesselschedule.aspx"
soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url).text )

table = soup.find_all('table')[6] # as it is not the best way as told by darkKnight
rows = table.find_all('tr')

data = []
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols])
print(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
res=requests.get("https://www.vit.org/WebReports/vesselschedule.aspx")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
```

find columns by below code:

```
table=soup.find_all("table")[6]
columns=[col.get_text(strip=True) for col in table.find("tr",class_="HeadingRow").find_all("td")[1:-1]]
```

find row data by below code:

```
main_lst=[]
for row in table.find_all("tr",class_="Row"):
  lst=[i.get_text(strip=True) for i in row.find_all("td")[1:-1]]
  main_lst.append(lst)
```

create table using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns,data=main_lst)
df
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need a way to specify a pattern that uniquely identifies the target table given the nested tabular structure. The following css pattern will grab that table based on a string it contains ("Shipline"), an attribute that is not present, as well as the table's relationship to other elements within the DOM.

You can then pass that specific table to read_html and do some cleaning on the returned DataFrame.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from pandas import read_html as rh

r = requests.get('https://www.vit.org/WebReports/vesselschedule.aspx').text
soup = bs(r, 'lxml')
df = rh(str(soup.select_one('table table:not([style]):-soup-contains("Shipline")')))[0] #earlier soupsieve version use :contains
df.dropna(how='all', axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.columns = df.iloc[0, :]
df = df.iloc[1:, :]
```